# How to add Custom pagination in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, pagination

i have created custom theme in wordpress.
I want to add custom pagination to my custom post template which is INDEX.PHP

Can you please check what is wrong in pagination script. actually i have set 4 post limit and there around 8 posts in my blog.. when click on 2 pagination, it won't move to next page...

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => the_post(),
    'posts_per_page'         => '3',
    'paged' => $paged
);
?>
<?php

// The Query
$cquery = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $cquery->have_posts() ) : $cquery->the_post();
?>
<div class="row">
                     <div class="img"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="imgPos"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?></a></div>
                        <div class="text">
                         <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" style="color:#545454;"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <h3 style="line-height: 1px;"><span class="floatL">By &nbsp;</span> <span class="floatL"> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> &nbsp;</span> <span class="floatL">&nbsp; - &nbsp;</span> <span class="floatL"><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></span><div class="clr"></div></h3>
                            <p><?php the_content('Read More') ?></p>
                           
                        </div> 
                        </div> 
<?php
$post->ID;
endwhile;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
?>
<div class="row">
<div class="pagination">
<?php
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' =>  $cquery->max_num_pages
) );
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Please help :)
Thank you,
Harshad Patil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE',
    'posts_per_page'         => '3',
    'paged' => $paged
);

// The Query
$cquery = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $cquery->have_posts() ) : $cquery->the_post();
echo $post->ID;
endwhile;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' =>  $cquery->max_num_pages
) );
```

Comment: How do i call pagination into post actually i'm very new to wordpress..please check with link http://equigreen.in/blog/ here i want to add pagination

Comment: please remove function named custom_pagination() from your template

Comment: As i understood that ... i have to copy your code in fucntion.php and anywhere i have to call ?

Comment: have u create template for custom post listing?

Comment: pls check with below
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  dynamic content here
 <?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: have you create template for custom post listing?

Comment: yes i added below endwhile loop ... then also its not working

Comment: please add whole code so that i can give my suggestion

Comment: <?php get_header(); ?>

<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  Here i have aded blog html markup
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php
Here i have add code that u have gave me
 ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: please create new template and put my code with get_header and footer function

Comment: and please put your post_type instead of  "YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE"

Comment: why we have top create new template. why can't we put in same template?

Comment: Hey vRajesh,,
I have not created new template, added code in same template.
and it is working!
:)

Thank you very much for precious support.

Comment: Rajesh please check with pagination in below url 
http://equigreen.in/blog/
its not wrapping posts

Comment: currently you got only post id

Comment: http://equigreen.in/blog/wp-content/themes/equigreen/index.zip

please download above....code
please check where i'm doing mistake

Answer (score 3):

Add Following code in "functions.php" file:

```
function custom_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2)
{  
 $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

 global $paged;
 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

 if($pages == '')
 {
     global $wp_query;
     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
     if(!$pages)
     {
         $pages = 1;
     }
 }   

 if(1 != $pages)
 {
     echo "<div class='pagination'>";
     if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
     if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
     {
         if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
         {
             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
         }
     }

     if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
     if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
     echo "</div>\n";
 }
 }
```

And in your "index.php" file add "custom_pagination();" after while loop.

Comment: How do i call pagination into post actually i'm very new to wordpress..please check with link equigreen.in/blog here i want to add pagination