# Pagination Fix Wordpress/CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

On the website, https://thearcadestick.com

The bottom pagination includes dots between the numbers.
How do I remove the dotsand only view the numbers?

This is the current code in:

```
`span.page-numbers.current {
color: white !important;
background: #2d2d2d !important;}`
```

Comment: `.page-numbers.dots{}`

Answer (score 0):

You can just hide the dots with CSS

```
.page-numbers.dots {
    display:none
}
```

But in this case it would be nice to hide also the last number - this is the penultimate item in the list:

```
.page-numbers li:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    display:none
}
```

Comment: 1.The second code you provided deletes that "last number" but it also deletes the "Next arrow". How do we just make sure it deletes the 'last number".  2. Also is there a way to add more numbers to the bottom of the page. (More than the current 4)

Comment: @FavoriteCodes 1) So, you can try to use also li:last-child selector to display arrow 2) If it needs to show more page numbers - you need to rebuild your pagination function or use custom one. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217677/how-to-add-custom-pagination-in-wordpress